# How to access Cloud SQL from dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a dataproc cluster and I'd like to have the cluster access a Cloud SQL instance. When I created the cluster I assigned scope `--scopes sql-admin` but after reading the [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/compute-engine-access) it looks like I need to connect through a proxy. How can I configure this for access from dataproc?

UPDATE:

Until integration comes out of the box (@vadim's answer) I can get this working by using cloud proxy in my dataproc initialization script:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64
mv cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 cloud_sql_proxy
chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
nohup ./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql --instances=my-project:us-central1:mysql-instance=tcp:3307 > cloud_proxy_nohup.log &
```

(note: port 3306 is already in use so Im using 3307 here)

Comment: Connecting from your own code or from an infrastructure service?

Comment: I'd like to connect from my own code (written in pyspark)

Comment: I would want to connect to Cloud SQL Postgres from dataproc and I have scala code, so I am using postgres-socket-factory, but i am hitting permission issue, How to access postgres using JDBC API through dataproc

Comment: any answer present for this now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pending pull request for a dataproc initialization action that will install the Cloud SQL Proxy on all the nodes in the cluster:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/47/commits/ade93cc25d72c33e176840ddaa50671e5ed8ed4a

Answer (score 1):

Using a VPC with a [private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip) between Cloud SQL and Dataproc seems to be a good option. A proxy should no longer be needed.

Comment: were u able to do this by following that doc, i couldnt, would u mind taking a look at this question? ( Thanks) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75380047/dataproc-hadoop-spark-job-can-not-connect-to-cloudsql-via-private-ip