# dataproc hadoop/spark job can not connect to cloudSQL via Private IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc, dataproc

I am facing this issue of setting up private ip access between dataproc and cloud sql with vpc network and peering setup, would really appreciate help since not able to figure this our since last 2 days of debugging, after following pretty much all the docs.

so far the setup i tried ( with internal IP only )

- enabled "private google access" to default subnet and used the default subnetwork for the dataproc and SQL.
- created the new VPX network/subnetwork and used that to create dataproc and updated cloud sql to use that network.
- created ip range and "private service connection" to "google cloud platform" service provider -- enabled it as well. Along with vpc network peering to "servicenetworking"
- explicitly added sql client role to default dataproc compute service account ( event though I didnt needed this for other VM connectivity to cloud sql, using the same role, because its a admin ("editor") role anyway. )
  [image]

All according to the doc : https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip and other links there

Problem:
when I submit spark job on dataproc that connects to this cloud sql, it fails with following error: Communications link failure....
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Test & debug:

- connectivity test all passes from the exact internal IP address on both side ( dataproc node and cloud sql node )
- mysql command line client can connect fine from dataproc master node
- checked cloud logging does not show any deny or issue in connecting mysql

screenshot for the connectivity test on both default and new vpc network. [image: connectivity_test_screenshot]

other stackoverflow questions I referred on using private ip:

1. [Cannot connect to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run after enabling private IP and turning off public iP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706513/cannot-connect-to-cloud-sql-from-cloud-run-after-enabling-private-ip-and-turning)
2. [How to access Cloud SQL from dataproc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512169/how-to-access-cloud-sql-from-dataproc)

ps: I want to avoid cloud proxy route to connect to cloud SQL from dataproc so dont want to install cloud_proxy service via initialization.

Comment: Does your Dataproc service account have the proper roles to connect to Cloud SQL (i.e. roles/cloudsql.client)?  I don't think the default Dataproc Worker SA has read/write access to Cloud SQL -- only GCS and BQ I believe.  In a normal compute engine, you'd also have enable the CloudSQL API in the VM's scope, but I don't think that's an option for Dataproc workers.

Comment: Yes, updated the question with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

A "Connection refused" normally means that nothing is listening on the other end. The logs also contain hints that the database connection is attempted to localhost, port 3307. This is the right port for the CloudSQL proxy, one higher than the usual MySQL port.

Check whether the metadata configuration for your cluster is correct:

**Workaround 1 :**

Check the proxy is a different version in the cluster that is having issues version 1.xx. The difference in SQL proxy version seems to be in this issue. You can pin the suitable version of Cloud SQL proxy to 1.xx.

**Workaround 2:**

Run the command : `journalctl -r   -u cloud-sql-proxy.service | grep -i err`,
Based on the logs check which sql proxy causes issues.

Check if the root cause may be the Data project was hitting "sql query per 100 sec per user" quota.

**Actions:**
Increase the Quota and restart the affected cloud sql proxy services (by monitoring jobs running on the master nodes that failed)
this is similar to the [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/288) but with the quota error preventing the startup instead of network errors in the link. With the updated quota, the cloud sql proxy should not have this reoccur.

**here's a recommended set of next steps:**

1. Reboot any nodes that appear to have a defunct/broken `cloudsql proxy -- systemd` won't report the truth, but running `"mysql --host ... --port ..."` trying to connect to the cloudsql proxy on the bad nodes would detect this.
2. Bump up API quota immediately - in Cloud Console just go to "IAM and Admin", go to "Quotas", search for the "Cloud SQL Admin API", click through it: then click on the pencil to "edit" and should be able to bump to 300 as self service without approval needed. If you want it to be more than 300 per 100s you might need to file an approval request.

3. If you look at the quota usage, if it's approaching 100 per 100s from time to time, update the quota to 300.

It's possible that the extra cloudsql proxy instances on the worker nodes are causing more load than is necessary just running cloudsql proxy on the master node.  If the cluster is only using a driver that runs on a master node, then the other worker nodes don't need to run the proxy.

To find the nodes which are broken, you can see which are responding to the cloud sql proxy port.

You can loop over each hostname and ssh to it and run this command:

```
nc -zv localhost 3307 || sudo systemctl restart cloud-sql-proxy
```

or you could check the logs on each to see which ones have logged a quota message like this:

```
grep cloud_sql_proxy /var/log/syslog | tail
```

and see if the very last message they see says "Error 429: Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'USER-100s' of service

```
'sqladmin.googleapis.com' for consumer ..."
```

The nodes which aren't running cloud sql proxy could be rebooted to start from scratch, or restart the proxy with this command on each:

```
"sudo systemctl restart cloud-sql-proxy"
```

Comment: Hi Veera, i am not using the cloud sql proxy at all, I am trying to connect to cloud sql instance directly using private IP address. which by the connectivity test it works fine.

Comment: also direct connectivity from the master node to SQL works as well
`nc -v <SQL_INSTANCE> 3306` returns `Connection to 10.47.0.3 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!`, its just that dataproc job fails with connection refused error.

Comment: Dataproc jobs fails connection refused and also due to inability to connect to shuffle service, because of not upgrading to a supported image version. Check the image version required to upgrade?

Comment: its using the latest image debian 11, spark 3.3.x, the communication within the dataproc nodes are all fine, i also see all "ALLOW" logs in log manager.

Comment: Can you try further along in direct proportion to some changes in memory allocation?

Comment: I have standard N2, 2vcpu and 8GB memory nodes, spark memory config is all within these resource limits, the app starts with connecting to db via hickaryCP, so no spark session etc kicked off yet. I already tried some random things, before posting here :)